# Adding a UISegmentedControl button to a toolbar within UITableViewController

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to add a toolbar with a `UISegmentedControl` appearing at the bottom of my view.
I am within a `UITableViewController`, which is embedded in a navigation controller which is embedded in tabbar controller. Usual drill down stuff.
I want this toolbar to only appear in this particular tab view. I use storyboards.

I tried creating a segmented control in the IB (storyboard), configuring its items and placing it within the viewcontroller catalog (that gray bar below the viewcontroller in the storyboard)

[image: storyboard]

adding a ref outlet of this segmented control to my viewcontroller.h
then unhiding the navcontroller toolbar and trying to add this item

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;

UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myOutletSegmentedControl];
self.navigationController.toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:segmentBarItem, nil];
```

So my `myOutletSegmentedControl` is uninitialized, even though I fully configured it in IB. 
So tried programmatically:

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;

UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a-b",@"b-a",nil]];

[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
segmentedControl.frame = self.navigationController.toolbar.frame;
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.momentary = NO;

UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
self.navigationController.toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:segmentBarItem, nil];
```

Now getting a toolbar at the bottom but with no items..

I even tried creating the whole toolbar -> child button -> child segmented control in IB and outletting it, then doing:

```
 self.navigationController.toolbar = myNewOutletToolbar;
```

Still no go.
I do prefer to use the storyboard/IB to create my UI, but I am pulling my hair out on it...

Comment: Try "self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES", it might work.